# Laravel method attributesToArray() not running on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm deploying my application to my production environment and it's not working as expected. I've narrowed the issue down to one line inside this loop in my controller;

```
foreach($temp_table_data as $a_payment) {
  //array_push($payments, $a_payment->payment); //big collection object
  array_push($payments, $a_payment->payment->first()->attributesToArray()); //smaller object
}
```

The error I get is `call to a member function attributesToArray() on a non object`. This seems crazy to be because - as the old saying goes - it works fine on my machine.

My dev. environment is Ubuntu trusty64 on PHP 5.5.21 and my production is RedHat Linux PHP 5.5.11. I thought these differences were very minor (maybe I'm wrong?).

If I do a `print_r($temp_table_data()` then I get a big collection returned. The same on both servers. So at some point it just stops liking either `payment` (that's a method) or `first()`

Here is partial of my TempTable.php Model with the payment method;

```
public function payment(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment', 'Vendor ZIP', 'postcode');
}
```

And my `Payment.php` model (part of it);

```
class Payment extends Model {

protected $table = 'headquarters_data';

public function tempTable()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TempTable', 'postcode', 'Vendor ZIP');
}
```

Comment: Perhaps consider `firstOrFail()` in case there are no results in payment()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the `tempTable` models doesnt have a `Payment` and the `attributesToArray()` method is failing.

Try this and see if it works.

```
foreach($temp_table_data as $a_payment) {
    $payment =  $a_payment->payment->first();
    if(!is_null($payment)){
          $payments[] = $payment->attributesToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Success! My data is loading. But how can you say my tempTable model doesn't have a payment? Is that not what I put in my original post? Whilst this answer worked, @Salar answer didn't. Although both a similar idea.

Comment: Can I also add - doing `print_r($payments)` on the "big collection object" (see original post) did return data. Sort of. It returned a collection for each one of my temp_table rows but the first 1000 or so were blank. Blank because there wasn't a succesful match. Maybe that was the problem? My test environment had much smaller datasets...

Comment: Yeah - I've just checked on my dev server. Every temp_table result has a matching payment record for it. so I was never getting an error. Damn, I never thought to test that. Tough lesson. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that in production you have probably changed the data in your database and calling to **first**() method returns **null** then you are trying to  call **attributesToArray**() on a **null**, which is wrong!
you should do a **isset()** function before calling attributesToArray().

```
if(isset($a_payment->payment->first()))
 array_push($payments, $a_payment->payment->first()->attributesToArray());
```

Comment: You basically made the same point as @PawelBieszczad I think but `isset` behaving slightly differently to `!is_null`. You were spot on about the data though. Thanks